# PHP static counter variable (not in function)

Tags: php, static

We have a view in our project that looks something like this

```
<?php
static $counter = 0;
$counter++
?>
<div id="item_<?= $counter ?>"> Item <?= $counter ?> </div>
```

The view is called multiple times per request, but the counter value always seems to be 1

This behaviour is somewhat different to the documented behaviour for static variables within a function*, but I couldn't find any documentation on static variables outside of functions or classes

**What is happening here? Why does this pattern work within a function but not outside? Does the static keyword have any value in this scope?**

*https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

---

**UPDATE**

On further investigation, and following some of the answers..

I think the views are effectively being 'inlined' one after another in the main script, so aren't scoped in the same way as a function that is declared once and then called multiple times

I would expect the same non-incrementing behaviour if I repeatedly declared and incremented the static counter twice in the same function

So my guess is that static variables outside functions aren't 'wrong' exactly, but do not have a valid use case

Comment: Whenever you execute this code it creates a static variable `$counter` with value `0`. Afterwards you increase it by 1. **It will always show 1.** You need some sort of database or file to store your value for `$counter`. If you want to get past 1.

Comment: If this is multiple view loads in the same execution of the script then you can use a global var and check if it is set and if so increment it.  If this is different executions then you need a session var.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal But why is that so different from static variables in functions? Using a database or a file would be a tad extreme

Comment: Yes, you need to store past value, if you want store temporary, you can use session variable.

Comment: @Arth **Because static variables gets destroyed after you executed your code (garbage collector).** So you need to store it somewhere. Session gets destroyed after your client closes the browser or when you actively destroy the session. You could store values in a cookie. But cookies are unique to the current client. Another client would have another value for `$counter`. You are forced to store the variable somewhere.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal I think you are confused. I don't need to save the value beyond the request, so its fine having it in a variable.. I just want it to increment it every time the view is rendered

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yah, that would work.. sorry, I have updated my question, I guess I'm more interested in why this behaviour is different, and whether using static can ever make sense outside of functions/classes

Comment: @Arth Yes i was indeed confused. Assuming now you have this code in a file. Whenever you execute the file you also execute the statement `static $counter = 0;` (Meaning it sets the counter value to 0, every time.) You need to define `$counter = 0` outside the file as @AbraCadaver mentioned.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal Evidently.. but the line `static $counter = 0;` **does not reset** the counter to 0 when used within a function, that was the difference I was asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`static`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) is only for use in functions:

> A static variable **exists only in a local function scope**, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

There are undoubtedly better ways based on the application structure and how you call the view etc..  but since this is a single execution of a script but multiple includes of the view file, you can use a global variable:

```
$GLOBALS['counter'] = ++$GLOBALS['counter'] ?? 0;
$counter = $GLOBALS['counter'];
```

If `$GLOBALS['counter']` is set then it will be incremented, if not it will be set to 0, then assigned to `$counter`.

For PHP < 7.0.0:

```
$GLOBALS['counter'] = isset($GLOBALS['counter']) ? ++$GLOBALS['counter'] : 0;
$counter = $GLOBALS['counter'];
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I only needed unique IDs for the HTML elements and had a variable I could pass down that sufficed

Answer (score 2):

If your div is in a loop (for example a foreach) you can be able to increase your counter like that:

```
<?php 
    
$counter = 0;
    
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $counter++;
    echo <div id="item_<?= $counter ?>"> Item <?= $counter ?> </div>
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `$counter` is in the main script (code in that file), and your main script will executed once, and after that your `$counter` will destroyed.

if your `$counter` is in the function, `$counter` will be increased every function called.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$counter` is being reset to 0 each time the view is generated, so it must be falling out of scope. Without more context on how the view is being generated it's hard to say why, but perhaps each time the view is being generated it is being done within it's own instance of a class?

One approach would be to initialize `$counter` in the global scope, and use it when generating the view

For Example:

```php
<?php

$counter=0;

function generateView(){      //<--- Whatever function being used to generate the view
  global $counter;
  $counter++;
  echo '<div id="item_'.$counter.'"> Item '.$counter.' </div>';
}

generateView(); //Generated the first time
generateView(); //Generated a second time

?>
```

(Realistically, if this *were* your code, using `static $counter=0` inside of the function would work as expected, but it's just an example of how a `global` variable **could** be used)

This approach is **not recommended** because global variables can get confusing, cause unexpected results, and IMO should generally be avoided.

There's almost certainly a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, but again, more context around *how* the view generation is being done will help guide a more helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think your example works better with the static inside of the function,  as it highlights the differences